# Should revisions with rude content be redacted?

Tags: discussion, edits, revision-history, rude-or-abusive

My question is triggered by this revision page: 
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59068233/revisions

When a rude post is made on the website we flag as R/A and it gets deleted as well as being obstructed from view by all users. You have to go to the revision page to see the content.

If a rude edit is made to a post, like it is the case here, then that edit is rolled back either by one of us or one of the mods. The content is not hidden in any way and can be easily seen by everyone who clicks the revision button. Not only the rude content is not deleted, but it can be easily accessed by everyone just by clicking one button.

Is there anything we can do about it and should we be concerned with this at all?

Comment: ...That's one user I wouldn't mind seeing suspended. They've probably received a warning at the very least, but indeed that does not fully hide the bad history.

Comment: There is nothing *really* offending in that revision... indeed it has bad language... but it's just repost of usual complain on meta or anywhere else... I don't see any particular reason why this variant needs to be removed completely...

Comment: Disagreed, @AlexeiLevenkov. If I were to call a group of people wankers and accuse them of being power-tripping fascist pricks, I would definitely be offensive. This form of toxicity being banal does not make it less offensive.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I often notice that in the US the term "Nazi" is used very easily. But for me coming from a country where that crap actually ruled it is one of the most severe insults I can imagine.

Comment: @E_net4theunsafedownvoter it'd be offensive if there was true weight behind it, but that is just a childish hissy fit. There are times to be offended and there are way, waaaaaaay more times to do no more than cringe and shake your head.

Comment: The true irony is that because of the OP's actions, they're in an even worse state than they were before; due to the question they kept editing ending up with a total of 10 down votes.

Answer (score 9):

No, this is not a reason to redact. Redaction is *destroying history*, and so we do it *very* sparingly.

Rolling back is sufficient.

If you want a moderator to take a look at a rude edit, then just raise a flag on the post and refer us to the problematic revision. It may well be warranted to take action against the submitter and, if applicable, the reviewers. (In this case, a moderator has already reached out to that user.)

Comment: If redaction is not the way to go here, is there any way to hide the rude content from majority of users? Is there a gap in the functionality not allowing mods to do this?

Comment: @Dharman Yes, it'll be hidden behind a link to the "/revisions" page.

Comment: This just feels like sweeping it under the rug. The revisions page is available to everyone even anonymous users. If the content is really abhorrent I think we should have better ways of hiding it other than behind a button in the post body.

Comment: The philosophy of Stack Exchange is that *all* revisions are tracked and displayed publicly. I don’t see a compelling reason to hide or suppress the display of this one or any other theoretical revision, offensive or not. If you want to go looking for it, it’s there, labeled clearly with the user who submitted it. It isn’t a limitation of the system. Moderators *can* redact it or any other revision, but we’re not going to. Redaction is used very sparingly because it has few checks and balances.

Comment: If someone wants to be offended by publicly available text, they don't need to go to the revisions page of Stack Overflow posts. I know of at least one twitter account I'm regularly offended by, and I don't even follow twitter...